# list remove() troubles

Tags: python, list

Remove() isn't working properly for me in this case where I am trying to remove elements from my list that do not contain a colon. Here is my list;

```
myList = ['hosts:127.0.0.1','-nU','-nT','-cA','-nB']
```

Doing `separated = myList.split(',')` and then

```
for i in separated:
    if ':' not in i:
    separated.remove(i)

print separated
```

leaves me with `['hosts:127.0.0.1', '-nT', '-nB']` as my output. I'm assuming this is because remove() only removes the first matching element. That still doesn't explain why -nt and -nb would be there though. What would a good alternative be to doing this?

Thanks

Comment: lesson learned. never remove items when iterating over a list. just create a new list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not modify your list as you iterate over it.

Use a copy instead or, more idiomatically, a list comprehension:

```
separated = [i for i in myList if ':' in i]
```

Comment: thanks. I got everything working on my end. I'll accept your answer when in 5 minutes when I am able to

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looping over the list as you are deleting elements. Consider this small alteration to your code:

```
myList = ['hosts:127.0.0.1','-nU','-nT','-cA','-nB']
for i in myList :
    print(i)
    if ':' not in i:
         myList.remove(i)
```

Output:

```
hosts:127.0.0.1
-nU
-cA
```

So your for loop never actually looks at two of the entries of the list.
You might consider using a list comprehension here as jpp has suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I just switched to that after I refreshed this page and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to go through each element of the list 
Like this 
`for i in range(0,len(myList)-1): 
         if ":" not in myList[i]:
                 myList.remove(myList[i])`

Comment: this gives an IndexError: list index out of range. My assumption is because you are altering the list as you are iterating through it

Comment: Change `len(myList)` to `len(myList)-1`